# Automate Heap Dump and Thread dump

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory, heap-dump

I am analysing an application for memory leaks and performance issue. I would like heap dump and thread dump created on certain conditions. JVM version is 1.6. Is there any possible way we can schedule Heap dump and thread dump whenever the heap memory usage increases up to 70% or before a full GC is triggered .

Comment: try to use jmx from outside

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMX to create a thread dump and a heap dump.

See [ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) for the thread dump

And [HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html) for the heap (might be specific to the oracle / sun jvm)

If you want to to it from within your application you can register a jmx monitor + listener to get a notification when the memory go over a given threshold.

If you wan to do it from another process, then you will need to pull the memory usage from a script (usually with jmx too...)
And then send a signal to jvm to get a heap + thread dump or use the jdk utilities (jstack + jmap)